# Interpolating R objects into R code strings

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using rpy2 to run some R commands. Dont ask why. It's necessary at this moment. So here's a part of the code.

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from rpy2.robjects import r

#Load emotionsCART decision tree. Successful.
r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(data)
print type(r_dataframe)
(<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame'>)

r('pred = predict(emotionsCART, newdata = %s)') %(r_dataframe)
```

Here what I want to do is pass this r_dataframe into the calculation. I'm using the decision tree that I'd loaded earlier to predict the values. But the last line gives me an error. It says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
r('pred = predict(emotionsCART, newdata = %s)') %(r_dataframe)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 245, in __call__
   p = rinterface.parse(string)
   ValueError: Error while parsing the string.
```

Ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You might want to check out IPython if you're working with Python and R. Here's an example using cell magic: https://gist.github.com/alexwoolford/c77f1fc87e37d8a572e4 It's really easy to move dataframes back and forth.

Comment: That would have been useful, but the thing is this part of the code  is a part of a bigger program which is again called by another python program. Stuck at this for a day now :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

```
r('pred = predict(emotionsCART, newdata = %s)') %(r_dataframe)
```

SHould be:

```
r('pred = predict(emotionsCART, newdata = %s)' % (r_dataframe) )
```

The `%(r_dataframe)` was associated with the `r()` part, while it should be associated with the `''` (string).

But it is hard to check without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, I tried that 

    r('pred = predict(emotionsCART, newdata = %s)' % (r_dataframe) ) 

Well I guess you do sth like taking out the ncol. I mean 
    r('ncol(%s)' % (r_dataframe) ) 
where r_dataframe is first read using pd.read_csv and then applying the conver to r dataframe function.

Comment: Also, I also found this. [link] http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/introduction.html#interpolating-r-objects-into-r-code-strings and it is working

Comment: If my answer fixed your issue, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of my answer. This signals that your question has been answered.

Comment: Hi Paul, No it didn't. This still gives an error. What I mentioned in my comments is - I tried passing the dataframe (using my method and yours too) to calculate the number of columns, but it gives the same error. "Error while parsing the string."